# Since today morning one of the DC's in my workplace changed it's hour to 2 hours late and I'm unable to find why

Tags: linux, windows-server-2008-r2, ntp

The server is getting NTP updates from a Linux server in the environment:

```
C:\Windows\system32>w32tm /config /update
The command completed successfully.

C:\Windows\system32>w32tm /query /status
Leap Indicator: 0(no warning)
Stratum: 3 (secondary reference - syncd by (S)NTP)
Precision: -6 (15.625ms per tick)
Root Delay: 0.0371704s
Root Dispersion: 7.7930820s
ReferenceId: 0x5250CC1A (source IP:  x.x.x.x)
Last Successful Sync Time: 1/8/2013 6:43:24 PM
Source: srvname.out.DOMAIN.com
Poll Interval: 6 (64s)
C:\Windows\system32>
```

That's the Linux NTP server:

```
[root@srvname ~]# hostname
srvname.out.DOMAIN.com
[root@srvname ~]# ntptime
ntp_gettime() returns code 0 (OK)
  time d496a4ae.61119000  Tue, Jan  8 2013 *15:59*:10.379, (.379174),
  maximum error 84347 us, estimated error 0 us
ntp_adjtime() returns code 0 (OK)
  modes 0x0 (),
  offset 0.000 us, frequency 5.091 ppm, interval 1 s,
  maximum error 84347 us, estimated error 0 us,
  status 0x1 (PLL),
  time constant 2, precision 1.000 us, tolerance 512 ppm,
[root@srvname ~]#
```

The time difference is my problem

Edit:

```
C:\Windows\system32>w32tm /query /status /verbose"
Leap Indicator: 0(no warning)
Stratum: 3 (secondary reference - syncd by (S)NTP)
Precision: -6 (15.625ms per tick)
Root Delay: 0.0370941s
Root Dispersion: 0.0435540s
ReferenceId: 0x5250CC1A (source IP:  x.x.x.x)
Last Successful Sync Time: 1/8/2013 6:55:25 PM
Source: srvname.out.DOMAIN.com
Poll Interval: 6 (64s)

Phase Offset: -7200.8865428s
ClockRate: 0.0156250s
State Machine: 3 (Spike)
Time Source Flags: 0 (None)
Server Role: 576 (Reliable Time Service)
Last Sync Error: 0 (The command completed successfully.)
Time since Last Good Sync Time: 17.0937177s
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try running w32tm /config /update in an administrator level command prompt (right click open as administrator)

Comment: it solved the access denied issue, thanks man, i don't know how i missed that, but the main problem is still in place.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the time is off, other than the possibility that the time zone itself changed, possibly.

The 0x01 isn't an error code in that "source" line, it's specifying the SpecialPollingInterval.  See here:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/w32time/archive/2008/02/26/configuring-the-time-service-ntpserver-and-specialpollinterval.aspx

do a "w32tm /query /status /verbose"

That will give you the last sync error if there is one.  If there isn't and it says "the command completed successfully" then I would look at the time zone itself or dig through the system eventvwr logs over the past 24 hours and see if there's an actual issue with the time.

Comment: I'm not sure what finally solved the issue but it's solved now, thanks anyways.